# Unable to redirect from one page to other using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Hope everyone doing well.

Actually I am a newbie to Rails. I am making a MCQS application for practice. I used Devise for authentication and I created a user model and controller and linked them with Devise.

Without using the Devise controller my application is working well, but I am unable to redirect from one page to my intended page.

Like: **I want to redirect from signup to login page** but it's not working.

When I use the Devise controller it says **argument error** and when I remove argument error it shows **params error.**

I don't know what to do, please help me how can I redirect from one page to other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your routes for devise `registrations` controller

```rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

And add this `RegistrationsController` to your controllers and `after_sign_up_path_for` method to it with path to redirect.

```rb
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

**Note**: If you use `devise :confirmable` in your `User` model you need to overwrite `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for`

```rb
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

And don't forget to restart your server.

Comment: bro but now for session controller it's showing error that Undefined local variable or method 'user' for Users session controller

Comment: I have written
if user.present? && user.authenticate(params[: password]) session[:user_id] = user.id then it's redirect to home page

Comment: Sorry but I don't know anything about your SessionContoller. That the code inside this controller and so on. The question was: "How to redirect from sign up to log in page". The errors in `session controller` it's already another question)

Answer (score 0):

If Rails 7, override the devise form (rails g devise:views) and custom view.
You will edit `registrations/new` and `sessions/new`

```
form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name) ) do |f|
```

replace

```
form_for(resource, as: resource_name, html: {'data-turbo' => "false"}, url: session_path(resource_name) ) do |f|
```

And change config/initializers/devise.rb

```
  config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :turbo_stream]
```